# need to change the author-year citation call-out style, elsarticle document class

Tags: citing, natbib, elsarticle

I have a little problem with the `model5-names` bibliography style in the `elsarticle` document class. Instead of getting

> (author, year)

citation call-out I'm having

> author (year)

How to get a parenthesis-style citation call-out?

Comment: Try using `\citet`. `natbib` discourages use of the generic `\cite` and recommends either `\citep` or `\citet`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should have been *try `\citep`* with **`p`** in my comment above. I think you could also try `\cite[]{key}`, but really using `\citep` is the better option.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're experiencing is not related directly to either the `elsarticle` document class or the `model5-names` bibliography style. Instead, it is caused by the following twin facts: (a) the `elsarticle` document class automatically loads the `natbib` citation management package; (b) if an author-year citation style (as is appropriate for the `model5-names` bibliography style) is in use, the `natbib` package treats `\cite{...}` (though not `\cite[]{...}`!) as an alias for `\citet{...}`, or "text-style citation".

What to do if you want to get a "parenthetic-style citation" rather than a "text-style citation"? Just type `\citep{...}`.

Comment: Point (b) is not entirely accurate. `\cite` actually behaves like `\citep` for numeric styles and its behaviour for author-year styles depends on the presence (or absence) of the optional argument, compare `\cite[]{sigfridsson}` and `\cite{sigfridsson}`.

Comment: @moewe - I've edited the answer to state explicitly that `\cite` is an alias for `\citet` *if* the `authoryear` option is passed to `natbib` (as should be done for the `model5-names` bibliography style). The fact that the outputs of `\cite[]{...}` and `\citep{...}` look the same is, in my opinion, more likely to be a fluke than a conscious design choice. At any rate, if the `natbib` package is in use -- as is the case if the `elsarticle` document class is employed -- one should be purposeful about the citation call-out forms and therefore not use `\cite`, but only `\citep` and `\citet`.